# Edit ntp.conf file using bash script to comment and replace lines

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, regular-expression

The output of current `/etc/ntp.conf` file in Debian 11:

```
# /etc/ntp.conf, configuration for ntpd; see ntp.conf(5) for help

driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift

# Leap seconds definition provided by tzdata
leapfile /usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list

# Enable this if you want statistics to be logged.
#statsdir /var/log/ntpstats/

statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable


# You do need to talk to an NTP server or two (or three).
#server ntp.your-provider.example

# pool.ntp.org maps to about 1000 low-stratum NTP servers.  Your server will
# pick a different set every time it starts up.  Please consider joining the
# pool: <http://www.pool.ntp.org/join.html>
pool 0.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
pool 1.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
pool 2.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
pool 3.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst


# Access control configuration; see /usr/share/doc/ntp-doc/html/accopt.html for
# details.  The web page <http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/AccessRestrictions>
# might also be helpful.
#
# Note that "restrict" applies to both servers and clients, so a configuration
# that might be intended to block requests from certain clients could also end
# up blocking replies from your own upstream servers.

# By default, exchange time with everybody, but don't allow configuration.
restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery limited
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery limited

# Local users may interrogate the ntp server more closely.
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1

# Needed for adding pool entries
restrict source notrap nomodify noquery

# Clients from this (example!) subnet have unlimited access, but only if
# cryptographically authenticated.
#restrict 192.168.123.0 mask 255.255.255.0 notrust


# If you want to provide time to your local subnet, change the next line.
# (Again, the address is an example only.)
#broadcast 192.168.123.255

# If you want to listen to time broadcasts on your local subnet, de-comment the
# next lines.  Please do this only if you trust everybody on the network!
#disable auth
#broadcastclient
```

I am trying to create a bash script that runs as root: It will comment out the four lines:

```
pool 0.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
pool 1.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
pool 2.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
pool 3.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
```

Remove the `#server ntp.your-provider.example` and replace with:

```
server jasper iburst
server cedar iburst
```

I can do the commenting out part but I am having issue with adding the server lines.

Here is my incomplete bash script:

```
#!/bin/env bash

ntp_file=/etc/ntp.conf

sed -i 's/^pool/#pool/g' $ntp_file

# Replace the commented out #server line with:

server jasper iburst
server cedar iburst 

# Restart the ntp service

systemctl restart ntp.service
```

Comment: If you want more help, you should rephrase your question. You're not asking about "commenting out lines", you're asking about editing a file via a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GNU awk for `-i inplace`, which I assume you have available since you're currently using GNU sed for that usage of `-i`:

```
awk -i inplace '
    { sub(/^pool/,"#pool") }
    /^#server/ {
        $0 = "server jasper iburst" ORS \
             "server cedar iburst"
    }
    { print }
' "$ntp_file"
```

Comment: I am getting an error `awk: not an option: -i`

Comment: Then you're not using GNU awk as I said was required, or you're using an old version that doesn't support `-i` in which case get a new version of gawk or just do `awk 'script' infile > tmp && mv tmp infile` like you would to overwrite the input file with any other command.

Comment: I am using `mawk 1.3.4 20200120`

Comment: `mawk 1` is an old, minimal featured awk. `mawk 2` is available I believe but just get gawk for excellent availability, features, performance, support, documentation, etc.